# Sources for Abraham's Link to Safa and Marwa

Tags: mecca

I'm looking for which Islamic sources explain the story of Abraham, Hagar, and Ishmael's affair with Safa and Marwa.

Online, every site I can find tells the story of Abraham leaving Hagar and Ishmael, and her running back and forth 7 times, but there aren't any sources cited.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sahih al-Bukhari 3365 narrates the story which mentions Safa and Marwa.

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas: When Abraham had differences with his wife),
> (because of her jealousy of Hajar, Ishmael's mother), he took Ishmael
> and his mother and went away. They had a water-skin with them
> containing some water, Ishmael's mother used to drink water from the
> water-skin so that her milk would increase for her child. When Abraham
> reached Mecca, he made her sit under a tree and afterwards returned
> home. Ishmael's mother followed him, and when they reached Kada', she
> called him from behind, 'O Abraham! To whom are you leaving us?' He
> replied, '(I am leaving you) to Allah's (Care).' She said, 'I am
> satisfied to be with Allah.' She returned to her place and started
> drinking water from the water-skin, and her milk increased for her
> child. When the water had all been used up, she said to herself, 'I'd
> better go and look so that I may see somebody.' She ascended the
> **Safa** mountain and looked, hoping to see somebody, but in vain. When she came down to the valley, she ran till she reached the
> **Marwa** mountain. She ran to and fro (between the two mountains) many times. They she said to herself, 'i'd better go and see the state
> of the child,' she went and found it in a state of one on the point of
> dying. She could not endure to watch it dying and said (to herself),
> 'If I go and look, I may find somebody.' She went and ascended the
> **Safa** mountain and looked for a long while but could not find anybody. Thus she completed seven rounds (of running) between **Safa**
> and **Marwa**. Again she said (to herself), 'I'd better go back and
> see the state of the child.' But suddenly she heard a voice, and she
> said to that strange voice, 'Help us if you can offer any help.' Lo!
> It was Gabriel (who had made the voice). Gabriel hit the earth with
> his heel like this (Ibn `Abbas hit the earth with his heel to
> Illustrate it), and so the water gushed out. Ishmael's mother was
> astonished and started digging. (Abu Al-Qasim) (i.e. the Prophet)
> said, "If she had left the water, (flow naturally without her
> intervention), it would have been flowing on the surface of the
> earth.") Ishmael's mother started drinking from the water and her milk
> increased for her child . Afterwards some people of the tribe of
> Jurhum, while passing through the bottom of the valley, saw some
> birds, and that astonished them, and they said, 'Birds can only be
> found at a place where there is water.' They sent a messenger who
> searched the place and found the water, and returned to inform them
> about it. Then they all went to her and said, 'O ishmael's mother!
> Will you allow us to be with you (or dwell with you)?' (And thus they
> stayed there.) Later on her boy reached the age of puberty and married
> a lady from them. Then an idea occurred to Abraham which he disclosed
> to his wife (Sarah), 'I want to call on my dependents I left (at
> Mecca).' When he went there, he greeted (Ishmael's wife) and said,
> 'Where is Ishmael?' She replied, 'He has gone out hunting.' Abraham
> said (to her), 'When he comes, tell him to change the threshold of his
> gate.' When he came, she told him the same whereupon Ishmael said to
> her, 'You are the threshold, so go to your family (i.e. you are
> divorced).' Again Abraham thought of visiting his dependents whom he
> had left (at Mecca), and he told his wife (Sarah) of his intentions.
> Abraham came to Ishmael's house and asked. "Where is Ishmael?"
> Ishmael's wife replied, "He has gone out hunting," and added, "Will
> you stay (for some time) and have something to eat and drink?' Abraham
> asked, 'What is your food and what is your drink?' She replied, 'Our
> food is meat and our drink is water.' He said, 'O Allah! Bless their
> meals and their drink." Abu Al-Qa-sim (i.e. Prophet) said, "Because of
> Abraham's invocation there are blessings (in Mecca)." Once more
> Abraham thought of visiting his family he had left (at Mecca), so he
> told his wife (Sarah) of his decision. He went and found Ishmael
> behind the Zamzam well, mending his arrows. He said, "O Ishmael, Your
> Lord has ordered me to build a house for Him." Ishmael said, "Obey
> (the order of) your Lord." Abraham said, "Allah has also ordered me
> that you should help me therein." Ishmael said, "Then I will do." So,
> both of them rose and Abraham started building (the Ka'ba) while
> Ishmael went on handing him the stones, and both of them were saying,
> "O our Lord ! Accept (this service) from us, Verily, You are the
> All-Hearing, the All-Knowing." (2.127). When the building became high
> and the old man (i.e. Abraham) could no longer lift the stones (to
> such a high position), he stood over the stone of Al- Maqam and
> Ishmael carried on handing him the stones, and both of them were
> saying, 'O our Lord! Accept (this service) from us, Verily You are
> All-Hearing, All-Knowing." (2.127)
>
> Sahih al-Bukhari 3365 https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3365